# Issues running first jsp application on host (Tomcat Server)?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Gee! Was I not the happiest geek on Earth when I finally finished my very first app yesterday? Everything was working and running fine on my local machine so I uploaded my app to my host on a running tomcat server. Followed the instructions, and put the app under /web-apps. Nice everything was going according to my plan. Then start browser type in www.myapp.com. Cool the index.jsp displays and everything else. So why not trying out that wonderful Jsp ecommerce app? Click on one category, 404 http error resource not available... Okay then try another one... Same... Click on view my basket, same error...

What's happening? It seems that the app once on host does not recognize the controller servlet? Or is it something else? Does this kind of issue have ever happened to you? How do I fix it if I don't even know where to look and what's causing the issues? What errors should I look for in the server logs?

Comment: Are they running under different context roots? Maybe your local instance is `localhost/myapp/` and the remote is `myapp.com/`? It could be the case that your links reference a particular root. (Just random guesses without seeing code or error logs).

Comment: @BeauGrantham: Yes my friend exactly... The app is in `tomcat/web-apps/myapp.com`... The `index.jsp` is in ROOT while the other pages are stored in `WEB-INF/view` But I tried to move the page views in the same directory as `index.jsp` and it did not solve the problem. I believe it has something to with the `controller servlet` I just cannot quite figure out what for now...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 404 error on browser which is most common and it occurs when page requested is not found.

You can configure your welcome page in web.xml for J2EE (Web Application) application. You can set either jsp or serlvet as your welcome page.

Following is the way of configuring welcome page in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServletProgramName</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myurl_pattern</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Myhtml.html</welcome-file>
(or you can even use your Servlet program name instead of HTML without any extension:
 <welcome-file>MyServletProgramName</welcome-file>)
    </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

Comment: I already have this configured in web.xml: `<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>`

Comment: And this for the index: `<jsp-property-group>
            <description>configuration for welcome page</description>
            <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jspf/error/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>`